# How to convert json object to datarow

Tags: c#-4.0

CommonRM objReports = new CommonRM();
objReports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(reportResponse.Result);

public class ReportList
    {
        public List ListofColumns { get; set; }

```
    public List<DataRow> ListofRows { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: model class :public class ReportList
    {
        public List<DataColumn> ListofColumns { get; set; }

        public List<DataRow> ListofRows { get; set; }

Comment: Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Data.DataRow. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'data.ListofRows[0].RowError', line 1, position 6433.